# CustomField not in Vaadin 13 beta1 prerelease?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin12

According to https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-13#custom-field, there should be a "CustomField" component in Vaadin 13 beta. However, when I tried to create one, my Java IDE couldn't find any reference to CustomField. (I then manually tried to search the maven imported files, and I still couldn't find CustomField.) Does it exist in the beta1 prerelease?

As well, the example of "mobile phone number" in https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-13#custom-field is exactly what we're looking for, but the corresponding java code below the picutre was not related to the picture....Is there a simple example (in Java) of how to achieve the "mobile phone number" field look shown in the https://vaadin.com/releases/vaadin-13#custom-field example? Here's the picture of what it's supposed to look like (taken from the vaadin prerelease website):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the POM for 13.0.0.beta1, and it is there in the list.  https://github.com/vaadin/platform/blob/13.0.0.beta1/vaadin/pom.xml#L86

Are you sure that you are using that version? Or have you modified the POM in some way to not include full platform? You could manually also add the same dependency to your own pom to see if the component gets available that way. Group id: vaadin.com
Artifact id: vaadin-custom-field-flow
Version: 1.0.0

Comment: CustomField flow integration should be included if you add a dependency to `vaadin` or `vaadin-core` artifacts. There was an issue in 13.0.0.beta1 and it's only included in `vaadin` artifact. The issue was fixed in https://github.com/vaadin/platform/pull/549 and will change will be included in beta2.